# I have mistakenly missed the FDE during install of 20.04.4 ubuntu how do I completed FDE post install?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, encryption

Good day and thank you for any feedback in advance. I very diligent in my OS setups. I cannot tell if I  missed the advanced options to complete FDE during my install on 20.04.4 focal fossa.

I am going to format a backup drive now. There are guides in the stack but they all involve backing up the disk, then unmount the native hardware SSD drive, reinstall the version of my back up, and encrypting via terminal certain folders and drives. I feel a bit unsafe as the FDE encryption is vital to overall security? I don't even know how to verify FDE.  Anyone please with guidance? Thank you

Comment: You weren't specific as to which Ubuntu 20.04 LTS product you're asking about; as Ubuntu offers Server/Desktop as well as many *flavors*.  In QA-testing post-install to confirm there is FDE, I reboot the *live* media from which I installed and expect on a full disk install to see only two partitions (or 1 for some installs), the / partition (*encrypted*) & ESP (*not encrypted as per ESP standards; this may or may not exist depending on installation media & hardware that it's installing to*).  If I can `mount` the `/` partition post-install without key, the install failed (ie. *no encryption*)

Comment: FYI:   Missing from prior comment (*due space*) i some installation media does not have an encrypted `/boot` by default; other 20.04 install media does. As you weren't specific as to 20.04 product this may/may-not apply in your case.  A FDE encrypted install should have no visible `/boot` though if FDE is offered  (*note: not all media offers this; with FDE provided with additional steps documented on the wiki for many older releases*)

Comment: thank you again. I have a system 76 Galago Pro 15.5 GiB15.5 GiB 500.1 GB storage 64-bit 3.36.8, 3.36.8, 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8